# Elasticsearch : Alternate approach to get frequency count without using aggregation

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-aggregation

We are trying to get the frequency count for search terms using aggregation. Since there are three keys for which we need to get the frequency count facing performance degrade with respect to search. How to get frequency count without aggregation? Please suggest some alternate approach.

Query:

`{
    "aggs": {
        "name_exct": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "name_exct": "test"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "name_exct_count": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "name_exct"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "CITY": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "CITY": "US"
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "CITY_count": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "CITY"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Please show the aggregation query that gives you trouble and the result you expect.

Comment: You can also try the [field stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-field-stats.html)

Comment: Please put that in your question and format it properly so people can read it

Comment: @Val Updated the post please provide your suggestion on this .

Comment: Field stats API is experimental and it will be removed from future release can we use this ? or any other approach available ?

Comment: I'm not certain that your aggregation query above is syntactically correct. Are you sure you copy/pasted it correctly?

Comment: experimental APIs **will not** be removed, but they **may** be removed (wording is important).

Comment: @Val please find the aggregation edited. This is the one which we are using.

Comment: It's the same as before and if you execute that you'll see an error `Could not find aggregator type [zipfreqCount] in [aggs]`. Something is missing...

Comment: @val could you please help on this